# Event for single tab in tab control

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I am trying to figure out how to make an event for a single tab in a `TabControl` for windows form.

I have tried some ways but the event always affect the whole `TabControl`, for example in this case my interface has one `TabControl` (`tabControl1`) with two tabs.

I would like it to be not possible to click the second tab before a reading process is going, also because while the reading process is going, the variables that I want to use in tab 2 don't have any values inside, a kind of protection.

```
private void tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (reading)    //Do not export when the program is reading
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You cannot export while reading. Please stop before exporting");
        return;
    }
    if (data[0] != null)
    {
        pesgo2.PeData.X[0, value] = (float)xCh0;
        pesgo2.PeData.Y[0, value] = (float)yCh0;
        pesgo4.PeData.X[0, value] = (float)xCh1;
        pesgo4.PeData.Y[0, value] = (float)yCh1;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for the code part, i tried to find the way to configure the right format, but looks like i didn't is my first time posting a code and i have some problems trying to understand the instructions, i am not English native speaker..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to handel the eevnt  `SelectedIndexChanged` like :

```
     private void tab1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             if ( reading==true &&  tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["tabname2"])//your specific tabname
             {
                  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You cannot export while reading. Please stop before exporting");
                  tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages["tabname2"];
                //To return to the previous tab if reading has not processing

             }
        }
```

Comment: I test it but i still don't get why nothing happens, i still can navigate through the tabs without restriction... your code make sense to me , but  i am sure i am not doing something right.... i will keep trying. thanks!

Comment: @Moloch  you can't have a tab that his name is "TabPages["Real Time"]" with space ,you must specify the name like "tabPage1" of tab not his caption "Real Time" .or use just index of tabs :TabPages[0].same for TabPages["Data Analysis"] use TabPages[1] it should work –

Comment: I am sorry it was my mistake but I corrected it ,your code works just perfect, thank you  very much!...

Comment: Did I ? haha sorry, i didnt notice it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`Selecting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event on the tab control, to stop the user from changing the tab until a condition has been met.

I'm not aware of any events available for a single tab that could help any further.

Comment: I try it but i still dont know how to use it very well, how about this?

`private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (reading)//your specific tabname   == true && tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["Data Analysis"]
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You cannot export while reading. Please stop before exporting");
                tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages["Real Time"];
                //To return to the previous tab if reading has not processing
            }`

Comment: @Moloch69 - You may want to update your question with what you have tried. if you want to stop the tab page from loading with this you can set `e.Cancel = true;`